# adding a checkbox against each item of a list in the view ( sharepoint 2007 )

Tags: sharepoint

In sharepoint 2007 i have created a list.

i am using a default view to add items to the list.

how can i add a checkbox against each item in the view. to select one or many items and then do something like copy these items to another list ?

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`ll just provide you with [a link to resource](http://www.2at.nl/blog/archive/2008/07/28/How_to_get_a_checkbox_in_a_list_definition_in_sharepoint_2007.aspx) and [another great example](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/03/05/select-multiple-list-items-in-sharepoint-feature.aspx) how to select and do action on multiple list items.